# Where can I find the Adobe Flash Player changelog or full release history?

Tags: security, flash, flash-player

I'm familiar with the Flash Player archives at Adobe, but I'd like to see the changelog for every minor public release of the Flash Player.  I've been searching with Google and on Adobe's site and still haven't found it.  We know the side-effects of the most recent releases VERY WELL, we just can't find a changelog that documents what Adobe has changed that has broken many of our web applications.  Does anyone know where this changelog/release history documentation lives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check their website: 
http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/releasenotes.html